# How to change the distance between the nodes and club them and bring them to center in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[remember picture,overlay,every node/.style={inner sep=2pt}]
\node[anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2]
at ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5in,-0.1\paperheight)$) {C};
\node[anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2]
at ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5in,-0.2\paperheight)$) {Y};
\node[anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2]
at ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5in,-0.3\paperheight)$) {B};
\node[anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2]
at ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5in,-0.4\paperheight)$) {Y};
\node[anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2]
at ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5in,-0.5\paperheight)$) {R};
\node[anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2]
at ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5in,-0.6\paperheight)$) {U};
\node[anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2]
at ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5in,-0.7\paperheight)$) {S};
\node[anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2]
at ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5in,-0.8\paperheight)$) {1};
\node[anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2]
at ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5in,-0.9\paperheight)$) {4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here , How do I reduce the distance between the nodes and  group them and  bring them in the center of  the margin.

Comment: What do you mean by "group them"? What king of grouping do you have in mind? Can you describe this in detail (or perhaps add an image showing the desired output?)

Comment: I meant grouping as the distance between them should be as minimum as possible but they should not touch and they should come at the center of the margin

Comment: The coordinate following the `+` defines the position of these nodes relative to `(current page.north east)`. So, changing that will adjust where the nodes are placed.  Alternatively you can place the nodes relative to each other, but without knowing exactly what you want to achieve it is difficult to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `positioning` library along with the key `node distance` for this. I have the box technique from Gonzalo as it is easy to put the center of box at page east.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2,inner
           sep=2pt,minimum width=0.6cm}}
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.1cm]
    \node[mynode] (c) {C};
    \node[mynode,below=of c] (y1) {Y};
    \node[mynode,below=of y1] (b) {B};
    \node[mynode,below=of b] (y2) {Y};
    \node[mynode,below=of y2] (r) {R};
    \node[mynode,below=of r] (u) {U};
    \node[mynode,below=of u] (s) {S};
    \node[mynode,below=of s] (1) {1};
    \node[mynode,below=of 1] (4) {4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at ($(current page.east)+(-0.5in,0)$) {\usebox\mybox};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the `node distance` will change the separation between nodes.

Answer (score 3):

One option using a chain to easily position the nodes and a box to save the initial contents; `node distance` can be used to control the distance:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,positioning}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain=going below,
  node distance=1mm,
  every node/.style={
    anchor=center,
    circle,
    fill=magenta,
    text=white,
    font=\sffamily,
    scale=2,
    inner sep=2pt,
    outer sep=0pt,
    on chain
    },
]
\node {C};
\node {Y};
\node {B};
\node {Y};
\node {R};
\node {U};
\node {S};
\node {1};
\node {4};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at ($(current page.east)+(-0.5in,0)$) {\usebox\mybox};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]