# LaTeX generating me 'Draft' text

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

Here is the code which I executed:

```
%Template for Technical Document
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\input{preamble/pakages.tex}
\input{preamble/quotations.tex}
\input{preamble/chapter_section_name_styling.tex}
\input{preamble/chapter_styling.tex}
\input{preamble/page_layout.tex}
\begin{document}
\input{articles/backtrack_linux.tex}
\end{document}
```

The output I get (first 2 pages are blank with watermark and draft is attached to pages and nodes appear only on first page):

[image]
Actaully I wanted to append this code to my file : [TikZ Circle Nodes 'Cybyrus14'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159656/how-to-change-the-distance-between-the-nodes-and-club-them-and-bring-them-to-cen/159720?noredirect=1#159720)

The code executed fine before making changes to few files. I made the following changes in these files or rather I suspect there is a problem in these files:

The page_layout.tex file:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,positioning}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\tikz[baseline={(0,0)},anchor=center]
    \node[label={center:\thepage},inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{images/apple}};}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
}


\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\tikz[baseline={(0,0)},anchor=center] \node[label={center:\thepage},inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{images/apple}};}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
\newcounter{thepagenum}
\setcounter{thepagenum}{0}

% Set highest row number to access
% '11' here because there are 11 rows in the .csv
\def\pagelimit{11}

\newcommand{\setquoteandauthor}{%
  \parbox[c][0.9cm][b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.5cm\relax}{%\centering
    \emph{\QValue} \hfill --- \AValue}}%

\AddEverypageHook{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\arabic{thepagenum}}{\pagelimit}=0
  \setcounter{thepagenum}{0}%
  \else
  \fi
  \stepcounter{thepagenum}
  \DTLgetvalue{\QValue}{quotes}{\arabic{thepagenum}}{1}%
  % Author info too?
  \DTLgetvalue{\AValue}{quotes}{\arabic{thepagenum}}{2}%
%  \fancyfoot[cf]{``\QValue'' --- \AValue}%
  \fancyfoot[cf]{\setquoteandauthor}}



\let\oldcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\afterpage{\thispagestyle{empty}}\oldcleardoublepage}

\pagestyle{myfancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\newwatermark[allpages,color=red!50,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{\transparent{0.2}\includegraphics[scale=.25]{images/logo}}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2,inner
           sep=2pt,minimum width=0.6cm}}
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.1cm]
    \node[mynode] (c) {C};
    \node[mynode,below=of c] (y1) {Y};
    \node[mynode,below=of y1] (b) {B};
    \node[mynode,below=of b] (y2) {Y};
    \node[mynode,below=of y2] (r) {R};
    \node[mynode,below=of r] (u) {U};
    \node[mynode,below=of u] (s) {S};
    \node[mynode,below=of s] (1) {1};
    \node[mynode,below=of 1] (4) {4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

For easy compilation I would rather give my all other files as well:

chapter_section_name_styling.tex

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,arrows}
\newcommand\titlebar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=0.5cm,trim right=2.5cm] {%
    \node [
        text = red!70!green,
        anchor= base east,
        minimum height=3.5ex] (a) at (2.5cm,0.6ex) {%
    };
   \path[fill=red!70!blue] (a.east) circle (.5ex);
   \draw[color=red!70!blue, thick,rounded corners=1ex] (a.east) |- (\textwidth+3cm,-0.75ex);
}%
}

\newcommand\subtitlebar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=1cm,trim right=3.05cm] {%
    \node[
        text = red!70!green,
        anchor= base east,
        minimum height=3.5ex] (b) at (3.05cm,0.6ex) {%
    };
   \path[fill=red!70!blue] (b.east) circle (.5ex);
   \draw[color=red!70!blue, thick,rounded corners=1ex] (b.east) |- (\textwidth+2cm,-0.75ex);
}%
}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\sf}{\subtitlebar}{0.2cm}{\textcolor{blue!60!green}{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{-2cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{name=\subsection,numberless}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}


\titleformat{\section}{\large\sf}{\titlebar}{0.25cm}{\textcolor{blue!60!green}{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-2.15cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{name=\section,numberless}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

chapter_styling.tex:

```
\newcommand\chapterauthor[1]{\authortoc{#1}\printchapterauthor{#1}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\chapterauthor*[1]{\printchapterauthor{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printchapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-25pt}%
  \linespread{1.5}\large\scshape\filcenter #1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}
\newcommand{\authortoc}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-10pt}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
    {\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize#1}{}{}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip5pt}%
}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
%  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\Huge\thechapter}
  {}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filcenter #1}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
```

packages.tex:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{suffix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,includefoot,footskip=1in,bindingoffset=0.2in,centering,headheight=0.3in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
```

quotations.tex:

```
\begin{filecontents}{csv_files/quotations.csv}
I\space think everybody in this country should learn how to program a computer because it teaches you how to think.; Steve Jobs
Computer Science is no more about computers than astronomy is about telescopes.; Edsger W. Dijkstra
The computer was born to solve problems that did not exist before.; Bill Gates
A\space computer would deserve to be called intelligent if it could deceive a human into believing that it was human.; Alan Turing
UNIX is basically a simple operating system but you have to be a genius to understand the simplicity.; Dennis Ritchie
Imagination is more important than knowledge.  For knowledge is limited, whereas imagination embraces the entire world, stimulating progress, giving birth to evolution.; Albert Einstein
The greatest enemy of knowledge is not ignorance, it is the illusion of knowledge.; Stephen Hawking
The more you know, the more you realize you know nothing.; Socrates
Tell me and I forget.  Teach me and I remember.  Involve me and I learn.; Benjamin Franklin
Real knowledge is to know the extent of one's ignorance.; Confucius
I~do not fear computers. I fear lack of them.; Isaac Asimov
\end{filecontents}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={quote,author}]{quotes}{csv_files/quotations.csv}
```

The backtrack_linux.tex:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node at ($(current page.east)+(-0.5in,0)$) {\usebox\mybox};
\end{tikzpicture}
\chapter{Install Backtrack on an Android Device}
\chapterauthor*{K.DINESH KUMAR \par II Year B.Tech CSE}
\section{What is Backtrack?}
BackTrack is a distribution designed by Jason Dennis based on the Ubuntu Linux distribution aimed at digital forensics and penetration testing use. BackTrack provides users with easy access to a comprehensive and large collection of security-related tools ranging from port scanners to Security Audit. Support for Live CD and Live USB functionality allows users to boot BackTrack directly from portable media without requiring installation, though permanent installation to hard disk and network is also an option.\par
\section{Security Tools in Backtrack}
BackTrack includes many well known security tools including:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Metasploit for integration
    \item Wi-Fi drivers supporting monitor mode (rfmon mode) and packet injection
    \item Aircrack-ng
    \item Gerix Wifi Cracker
    \item Kismet
    \item Nmap
    \item Ophcrack
    \item Ettercap
    \item Wireshark (formerly known as Ethereal)
    \item BeEF (Browser Exploitation Framework)
    \item Hydra
    \item OWASP Mantra Security Framework, a collection of hacking tools, add-ons and scripts based on FirefoX.
    \item Cisco OCS Mass Scanner, a very reliable and fast scanner for Cisco routers with telnet and enabling of a default password.
\end{itemize}

\section{Installing Backtrack on Android Device}
\subsection{Tools Required}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Backtrack 5 ARM.\\
Download Backtrack 5 ARM from Backtrack official site. Backtrack with ARM architecture only on Backtrack 5 version. ARM architecture not available for Backtrack 5 R1, Backtrack 5 R2, and Backtrack 5 R3.
\item Rooted android device \\
Why rooted android device ? Because we need install some application that need Android to be root
\item Busybox, Superuser, Terminal Emulator, and AndroidVNC. \\
You can download search and all of them on Google Play. BusyBox is installer and uninstaller Android program, Superuser is superuser rights manager for Android, Terminal Emulator is Android's built-in Linux command line shell program, and AndroidVNC is a VNC viewer for Android.
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{Installation}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Extract BT5-GNOME-ARM.7z to folder, for example "BT5" folder and then put on device root directory.
\item Open Terminal Emulator on device then go to BT5 folder using the command \verb+ cd sdcard/BT5 +
\item Then run this following command \verb+ su + and \verb+ sh bootbt + and you will see \verb+ root@localhost +
\item Now lets run Backtrack GUI with VNC viewer \verb+startvnc+
\item To connect wth VNC we must know the port where VNC listening. Run \verb+netstat -anpt+ and remember the port where VNC listening. In this case the port is 59016. Open AndroidVNC and fill the form like this: \\
Nickname : BT5\\
Password : toortoor\\
Address  : 127.0.0.1\\
Port     : 5901 \\
\item Connect it and you will see Backtrack 5 interface \par
\textit{Remember! Some of the Backtrack tools can't work properly and do it for your own risk. I hope you can Install Backtrack on Android device without any problems, tell me if you get problems.}
\end{enumerate}
```

The quotations.csv file:

```
%% LaTeX2e file `csv_files/quotations.csv'
%% generated by the `filecontents' environment
%% from source `technical' on 2014/02/11.
%%
I\space think everybody in this country should learn how to program a computer because it teaches you how to think.; Steve Jobs
Computer Science is no more about computers than astronomy is about telescopes.; Edsger W. Dijkstra
The computer was born to solve problems that did not exist before.; Bill Gates
A\space computer would deserve to be called intelligent if it could deceive a human into believing that it was human.; Alan Turing
UNIX is basically a simple operating system but you have to be a genius to understand the simplicity.; Dennis Ritchie
Imagination is more important than knowledge.  For knowledge is limited, whereas imagination embraces the entire world, stimulating progress, giving birth to evolution.; Albert Einstein
The greatest enemy of knowledge is not ignorance, it is the illusion of knowledge.; Stephen Hawking
The more you know, the more you realize you know nothing.; Socrates
Tell me and I forget.  Teach me and I remember.  Involve me and I learn.; Benjamin Franklin
Real knowledge is to know the extent of one's ignorance.; Confucius
I~do not fear computers. I fear lack of them.; Isaac Asimov
```

The images :
[image]
[image]

I want the nodes at every page and at right side for the pages on the right and on the left side for the pages on the left .

Comment: You are loading the `background` package which will typeset "Draft" by default. Either don't load the package or make the necessary adjustments to avoid the "Draft" message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add these in your `page_layout.tex` file:

```
\tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2,inner
           sep=2pt,minimum width=0.6cm}}
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.1cm]
    \node[mynode] (c) {C};
    \node[mynode,below=of c] (y1) {Y};
    \node[mynode,below=of y1] (b) {B};
    \node[mynode,below=of b] (y2) {Y};
    \node[mynode,below=of y2] (r) {R};
    \node[mynode,below=of r] (u) {U};
    \node[mynode,below=of u] (s) {S};
    \node[mynode,below=of s] (1) {1};
    \node[mynode,below=of 1] (4) {4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
color=black,
contents={%
 \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node at ($(current page.east)+(-0.5in,0)$) {\usebox\mybox};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node at ($(current page.west)+(0.5in,0)$) {\usebox\mybox};
\end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi
}
}
```

You have not added the

```
\backgroundsetup{.
.
.
.
}
```

part. This is the reason you are getting `Draft` in your pages.  And remove

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node at ($(current page.east)+(-0.5in,0)$) {\usebox\mybox};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

from the `backtrack_linux.tex` file.

A MWE will be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,bindingoffset=0.2in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=center,circle,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\sffamily,scale=2,inner
           sep=2pt,minimum width=0.6cm}}
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.1cm]
    \node[mynode] (c) {C};
    \node[mynode,below=of c] (y1) {Y};
    \node[mynode,below=of y1] (b) {B};
    \node[mynode,below=of b] (y2) {Y};
    \node[mynode,below=of y2] (r) {R};
    \node[mynode,below=of r] (u) {U};
    \node[mynode,below=of u] (s) {S};
    \node[mynode,below=of s] (1) {1};
    \node[mynode,below=of 1] (4) {4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
color=black,
contents={%
 \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node at ($(current page.east)+(-0.5in,0)$) {\usebox\mybox};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node at ($(current page.west)+(0.5in,0)$) {\usebox\mybox};
\end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi
  }
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]